# No overlapping between two paths - creating "one line" - how?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cc-2015

I have two paths and I want them to be exact in one line.

I tried to do this by hand, but this not exact - there is an overlapping area between the two paths. How can I change that?

[image]

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CC 2015.

Comment: Search for path operations, or the pathfinder. Have you tried subtract one shape from another?

Comment: But this is really not what I wanna do. It should like a country, each country has his border - the border to cross the other country. No no-mans land. It's working perfectly with a vector point - when you create a new one over an existing one, it said "anchor". I want the same function here for this "border".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one thing that could work: picking one of the two overlapping segments and simply deleting it so the other stands alone.

1. Find the **Scissors Tool** on your Tools Panel. If it isn't showing up, look for either the Eraser Tool or the Knife, then right-click it to reveal the options for that Tool Panel slot. The Scissors Tool should appear in a small menu. Here are the icons for CC 2016, which should be similar to what you're looking for...

[image]

2. Pick one of the two segments that you would like to keep. Find the path associated with that segment, and then select the *other* path.
3. Choose two points on this path for making your cuts. Everything on this path between those points will made into a separate path (on a separate layer).
4. Select this separate path and delete
5. OPTIONAL: Grouping the remaining paths, so that they will stay in the same place relative to each other.

Hope this helps!!